# Ajax POSTs data inspite of false Twitter bootstrap form validation

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation

I am trying to submit a form and send the data to my php function with Ajax. The problem is that, When I send data without ajax call and just using form action, My form validation works, but when I want to use Ajax, Form will be submitted without being validated. Here is my code:
html:

```
    <form novalidate="" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email address</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="email" required="" id="email" name="email">
                            <p class="help-block">Email address we can contact you on</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="emailAgain" class="control-label">Email again</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="email" name="emailAgain" id="emailAgain" data-validation-matches-message="Must match email address entered above" data-validation-matches-match="email">
                            <p class="help-block">And again, to check for speeling miskates</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <button id="button" class="button" type="submit" name="submit">Check your


                </form>
```

Ajax:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
            $('.error').hide();

            // Process form

            var email = $("input#email").val();

            var emailagain= $("input#emailagain").val();

            var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&emailagain=' + emailagain;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "send_email.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("Thank you ")
                        });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

I also tried `submitHandler: function(form){}` with Ajax call, but in that case, my success function in Ajax call won't work and it seems that the data will be sent through GET method instead of POST! weird!!! Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you have a submit button and on clicking this you are doing some ajax, so you need to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Here how the code should be and it should work, also check for any syntax error in your code. Below is the code I just tested and worked on my linux box.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(function () {
        $("#button").click(function (x) { 
        x.preventDefault(); // lets stop the default behaviour which is submit 
            $('.error').hide();

            // Process form

            var email = $("input#email").val();

            var emailagain= $("input#emailagain").val();

            var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&emailagain=' + emailagain;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "send_email.php",

                data: dataString,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("Thank you ");
                 }
             });

          });
          return false;
       });  
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing the function. But it still doesn't work. It works as if the function didn't exist. Is that normal?

Comment: I did not get , once you add $("#button").click(function (x) { <-- x and then use x.preventDefault(); it will not submit the form. Then the next set of JS code will get executed and it will call the ajax and return the message as you did, but page will never refresh. I saw some syntax error in your original code, the code that I added is after fixing the syntax errors. You add my code directly and see what happens? More over make sure that jquery is loaded on your page.

Comment: Now it works, but it seems that x.preventDefault(); doesn't allow the button to be clicked anyway. Now the form validation happens, but even when it's valid, data will not be sent!

Comment: Not sure but the submit button should be clickable, you may not realize it since its not submitting the form, you can add some alert inside the js onclick event and you can see its working.

Comment: I did! I added the alert in success function and it didn't work!

Comment: hmm are u sure that the file send_email.php is getting called ? or the file is in some other location ? Also you may need to check the code for the email sending. You may post the code in codepad.org and share the link here

Comment: I'm using codeigniter so the url is actually based on codeigniter url helper and it's correct. Everything works perfectly, Just ignoring the form validation.

Comment: I can handle data in my php file. The only thing I want now is if there's a way that my success function wouldn't work if form is not valid. P.S. I'm expert in PHP but I'm new to AJAX! So I will appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: hmm its the twitter bootstrap validator and I suppose you have different function somewhere which is validating. You can do a small JS code inside the onclick if email is not empty then only call the ajax

Comment: Yes! I think I will finally have to add my validation rules just before my Ajax call using a $('#form').validate() function. I will see if it works! Thanks a lot Abhik!

Comment: Do one thing in your PHP file get the data with $_POST and check the required fields and if required fields are not there just do echo '0' else process the form and echo "success",in the ajax part you can do like success: function (data) { if(data.trim() == '0'){ // show error message in a div } else { // sucess what u are doing now }